# Meaning of the headline 超流量平台

Tags: translation, terminology

The 平台 is usually rendered as 'platform', but what is the 超流量?

The total context of the phrase is as follows:

是俄罗斯及市场最新颖的垂直跨境电商零售批发网站。未来平台注册用户数将超过1000万+，日均访问UV超过100万+，PV超过0.5亿+，最大化展现平台流量价值.

So would it be 'a site / a platform / an Internet space (Russian 'ploshchadka') with highest [Internet] traffic'?

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding (highest [Internet] traffic) seems correct, given that it is used on an e-commerce site.

But I want to point it out that it is not a standard/correct word. Chinese have a lot of freedom in coining new words but not all of them are fine ones. Of most IT-related idioms, 超 is translated from hyper, so we have 超链接(hyperlink), 超文本传输协议(HyperText Transfer Protocol), etc.

Nobody can give an exact meaning of 超流量平台 because it is not a standard IT idiom published by 全国科学技术名词审定委员会（China National Committee for Terms in Sciences and Technologies ）. That's why I said in my previous answer, it is just an ill-devised fancy word.

Comment: So, can 超 be reated to and describe the 平台?

Comment: in short, no. "超流量平台" is a lousy retouch of an already awful term "流量平台", which does not make any sense to anyone who is not of the SEO and e-commerce industry.

Answer (score 0):

超 = super

流量 (flow volume): describes the volume of a moving body of water. It is often borrowed to describe **交通**量 (**traffic** volume)

超流量 = 超(大)流量 - '**super (high) traffic volume**'